# Arraylist getting sorted when it's not supposed to?

Tags: java, arraylist, scope

I'm getting very frustrated from this problem I have. Here is the gist of what is happening:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(12);
        list.add(19);
        list.add(442);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(9);
        out.println(list.toString());
        out.println(bubbleSort(list));
        out.println(list.toString());
    }
    public static int bubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> num) {
        int j;
        boolean flag = true;
        int temp;
        while(flag) {
            flag = false;
            for(j = 0; j < num.size() - 1; j++) {
                if(num.get(j) > num.get(j + 1)) {
                    temp = num.get(j);
                    num.set(j, num.get(j + 1));
                    num.set(j + 1, temp);
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return num.get(0);
    }
}
```

The output is:

`[12, 19, 442, 3, 1, 9]
1
[1, 3, 9, 12, 19, 442]`

Why is the ArrayList `list` getting sorted when I call the method `bubbleSort()`? Shouldn't the method be making an instance of `list` when I call it as `bubbleSort(list)` and not sort `list` itself which is outside its scope? I just want `bubbleSort` to get the smallest value of `list` by making an instance of `list`, sorting that instance using bubble sort, and returning the first value of that instance. Am I missing something really obvious? I've gotten really tired from my frustration over this problem...

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: In Java, you make a new instance with the `new` keyword, and you only do it once in your snippet, in `main()`.

Comment: @assylias: We really need a canonical for "what is an object reference" that doesn't get into the whole pass-by- thing at all, as it's irrelvant to 95% of the questions where people don't understand this. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

num has been save by ref and not by value so what you need to do it's that code

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(12);
        list.add(19);
        list.add(442);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(9);
        out.println(list.toString());
        out.println(bubbleSort(list));
        out.println(list.toString());
    }
    public static int bubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> num) {
        //copy the array list to new array list
        ArrayList<Integer> numtemp = new ArrayList<Integer>(num);
        int j;
        boolean flag = true;
        int temp;
        while(flag) {
            flag = false;
            for(j = 0; j < numtemp.size() - 1; j++) {
                if(numtemp.get(j) > numtemp.get(j + 1)) {
                    temp = numtemp.get(j);
                    numtemp.set(j, numtemp.get(j + 1));
                    numtemp.set(j + 1, temp);
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return numtemp.get(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. My comp sci course never taught me about pass by reference and pass by value... guess I have some reading to do.

Comment: @parrot15: Just to be clear: This is **not** pass-by-reference. "Pass-by-reference" is a term of art referring to passing references to *variables* so the called method can reach out and change the value in the variable. Java never does that. Java does have object references, but those are passed by value just like everything else.

Answer (score 4):

> Shouldn't the method be making an instance of `list` when I call it as `bubbleSort(list)` and not sort `list` itself which is outside its scope?

No. Passing around the value that refers to an object (called an *object reference*) doesn't involve copying the object, just the value.

The value in your `list` variable is an object reference, which tells the JVM where that list object is in memory. (We never see the actual values, but think of them as numbers like `int`s; they behave exactly like them.) If you pass that value into a method, the method receives a copy of that value (the object reference) — but that object reference still refers to the same object.

It's exactly the same thing as what happens here:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = list1;
```

Let's break it down. When we do

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

the `new` operator makes the JVM create an `ArrayList` in memory, and store a reference to that list (a unique identifier for it that the JVM understands) in `list1`:

```
list1<Ref22135>−−−+
                  |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  +−−−>| (ArrayList)  |
                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                       | count: 0     |
                       | capacity: 16 |
                       | ...          |
                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then when we do this:

```
List<String> list2 = list1;
```

that value (shown above as Ref22135, but again, we never see them) is *copied* into `list2`:

```
list1<Ref22135>−−−+
                  |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  +−−−>| (ArrayList)  |
                  |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
list2<Ref22135>−−−+    | count: 0     |
                       | capacity: 16 |
                       | ...          |
                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

We now have two copies of the reference to the single object, not two objects.

For the same reason, passing `list` into `bubbleSort` copies the *value* of the `list` variable (Ref22135 or whatever) into the `bubbleSort` parameter, not the list itself.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now, thanks. Although I don't get the purpose of why they made it so that when I pass list into `bubbleSort()` that it makes an instance of the _memory address_, rather than the values of list itself.

Comment: @parrot15: Duplicating an object every time you pass it into a method would be **massively** inefficient (and don't forget it would have to be a deep copy, by definition). Whereas duplicating a reference is a matter of copying four to eight bytes (into JVM registers or onto the stack).